Spring boot upgrade 3.1.11 to 3.2.5 org.hibernate.query.SemanticException date conversion
I am getting this error, its because of that -60 and -(0.5/24) in the date. Is there a different way to do this so it is equivalent in this new version of hibernate? We are using Oracle DB
Operand of - is of type 'java.lang.Integer' which is not a temporal amount (it is not an instance of 'java.time.TemporalAmount')    

sample source:
@Repository
interface APCheckRepository extends JpaRepository<APCheck, Long> {
    @Query("select abcfrom TestTable abc"
        + " WHERE abc.checkDate >= ORACLE_TRUNC(current_date-60))
    List<TestTable> findSomething(); 
}

and another example
@Query("select d from TestTable2 d where "
        + "  d.dateOfService-(0.5/24) <= :dosTo " // dateOfService within 30 mins of dosTo
        + "  and d.dateOfService-(23/24) <= :dos " // dateOfService within 23 hours of dos
        + "  and d.dateOfServiceTo-(24.5/24) <= :dos " // dateOfServiceTo within 24 1/2 hours of dos
        + "order by"
        + "  d.quantity")
List<TestTable2> findSomething2( 
        @Param("dos") Date dos,
        @Param("dosTo") Date dosTo);

custom code here to reuse the old 2.7 supported syntax
public class CustomOracleDialect extends OracleDialect {

    public CustomOracleDialect() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register("ORACLE_REGEX_UPPER_ALPHANUM", new StandardSQLFunction("REGEX_UPPER_ALPHANUM"));
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register("ORACLE_TRUNC", new StandardSQLFunction("trunc"));
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register("ORACLE_UPPER", new StandardSQLFunction("upper"));
   }

}


There are 2 ways to solve this, the most straightforward is just to adjust the parameters being passed in to add the time.
DateUtils.addHours(visit.getDOS(),23)

Another way if it isn't a parameter is to do a custom function
functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register("ORACLE_DATEADD", new 
    PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor(
            new PatternRenderer("(?1 + INTERVAL ?2 DAY)"),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "ORACLE_DATEADD",
            FunctionKind.NORMAL,
            null
    ));

